# how to show new email with different color in my email application design using laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, imap

I have created a system, in which i grab the inbox and display it on one page. Newly received email automatically comes first. But now I have to show a mark or a different color that will tell the user this is new mail. How can I do this using laravel 5.

here is my controller method:

```
    public function getMail()
{
    /* connect to gmail */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $password = 'xyz';
    /*Get all the data in $inbox*/
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
    /*collect ALL the messages in inbox*/
    $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
    /*Collect unread messages only*/
    $emails_unread = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN');
    /*Count rows from table 'Email'*/
    $row_count = count(Email::all());

    $email_count = count($emails);
    $emails_unread_count = count($emails_unread);
    /*For the first time when a new email is added*/
    if($row_count == 0){
        rsort($emails);
        foreach($emails as $all_email){
            $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$all_email);
            $message = quoted_printable_decode (imap_fetchbody($inbox, $all_email, 1));
            $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
            $toaddress = $header->toaddress;
            $message_number =  $header->Msgno;
            Email::create(['from'=>$from, 'body'=>$message , 'message_no'=>$message_number]);
        }
        return $this->show();
    }
    /*when a new email gets added, compare stored email numbers with new email count */
    elseif($row_count < $email_count){
        rsort($emails_unread);
        foreach($emails_unread as $unread){
            $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $unread);
            $message = quoted_printable_decode (imap_fetchbody($inbox, $unread, 1));
            $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
            $toaddress = $header->toaddress;
            $message_number =  $header->Msgno;
            Email::create(['from'=>$from, 'body'=>$message , 'message_no'=>$message_number]);
        }
        return $this->show();
    }
    /*IF both above fails*/
    else{

        return $this->show();
    }
    imap_close($inbox);
}
```

Comment: Just clearing my doubt: Are you making your own Email System ?

Comment: yes, just inbox! not all

Answer (score 0):

1. Create View in Laravel to display this data
   [Laravel - Views](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views)
2. Add css file to this View with specific class for unseen emails
3. Display data with color background for unseen mails